# NodeJS Express Docker Instance exited with code 0

Tags: node.js, express, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

## Goal

I have 3 instances in my `dockercompose.yml` , I can only start 2 of my instances, and have a hard time starting my third one which my node express.

---

## Project directory

```
.
├── Icon\r
├── angular
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── dist
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── style.css
│   │   ├── img
│   │   │   ├── external.png
│   │   │   ├── favicon.png
│   │   │   ├── footer_logo.png
│   │   │   └── logo.png
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── js
│   │       ├── bundle.js
│   │       └── vendor.js
│   ├── docs
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   ├── api.js
│   │   │   ├── app.config.js
│   │   │   ├── app.module.js
│   │   │   └── guide.js
│   │   ├── build
│   │   │   ├── index.html
│   │   │   ├── partials
│   │   │   │   ├── api
│   │   │   │   │   ├── common
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── directive
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   └── app.html
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── directive.html
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── type
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   ├── AppController.html
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   └── AppSidebarController.html
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── type.html
│   │   │   │   │   ├── common.html
│   │   │   │   │   ├── components.auth
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── service
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   └── AuthService.html
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── service.html
│   │   │   │   │   ├── components.auth.html
│   │   │   │   │   ├── components.contact
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── directive
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   └── lengthCheck.html
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── directive.html
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── service
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   └── ContactService.html
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── service.html
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── type
│   │   │   │   │   │   │   └── ContactEditController.html
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── type.html
│   │   │   │   │   ├── components.contact.html
│   │   │   │   │   └── components.html
│   │   │   │   ├── api.html
│   │   │   │   ├── guide
│   │   │   │   │   └── howTo.html
│   │   │   │   └── guide.html
│   │   │   └── src
│   │   │       ├── api-data.js
│   │   │       ├── api.js
│   │   │       ├── app.config.js
│   │   │       ├── app.module.js
│   │   │       ├── guide-data.js
│   │   │       └── guide.js
│   │   ├── config
│   │   │   ├── index.js
│   │   │   ├── processors
│   │   │   │   ├── api-data.js
│   │   │   │   ├── guide-data.js
│   │   │   │   └── index-page.js
│   │   │   └── templates
│   │   │       ├── constant-data.template.js
│   │   │       ├── content.template.html
│   │   │       ├── indexPage.template.html
│   │   │       └── module.template.html
│   │   └── content
│   │       ├── api
│   │       │   └── index.md
│   │       └── guide
│   │           ├── howTo.md
│   │           └── index.md
│   ├── files
│   │   ├── default.conf
│   │   └── nginx.conf
│   ├── gulpfile.babel.js
│   ├── karma.conf.js
│   ├── mocks
│   │   └── firebase.mock.js
│   ├── npm-shrinkwrap.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   ├── common
│   │   │   │   ├── app-footer.component.js
│   │   │   │   ├── app-footer.html
│   │   │   │   ├── app-header.component.js
│   │   │   │   ├── app-header.html
│   │   │   │   ├── app-pagination.html
│   │   │   │   ├── app-pagination.js
│   │   │   │   ├── app-sidebar.component.js
│   │   │   │   ├── app-sidebar.html
│   │   │   │   ├── app.component.js
│   │   │   │   ├── app.html
│   │   │   │   ├── app.module.js
│   │   │   │   ├── app.spec.js
│   │   │   ├── components
│   │   │   │   ├── auth
│   │   │   │   │   ├── auth-form
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── auth-form.component.js
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── auth-form.controller.js
│   │   │   │   │   │   ├── auth-form.html
│   │   │   │   │   │   └── auth-form.spec.js
│   │   │   │   │   ├── auth.module.js
│   │   │   │   │   ├── auth.spec.js
│   │   │   │   │   └── login
│   │   │   │   │       ├── login.component.js
│   │   │   │   │       ├── login.controller.js
│   │   │   │   │       ├── login.html
│   │   │   │   │       └── login.spec.js
│   │   │   │   ├── components.module.js
│   │   │   │   └── dashboard
│   │   │   │       ├── access-point-map
│   │   │   │       │   ├── access-point-map.component.js
│   │   │   │       │   └── access-point-map.html
│   │   │   │       ├── account-stats
│   │   │   │       │   ├── account-stats.component.js
│   │   │   │       │   └── account-stats.html
│   │   │   │       ├── dashboard.component.js
│   │   │   │       └── dashboard.html
│   │   │   ├── root.component.js
│   │   │   ├── root.html
│   │   │   └── services
│   │   │       ├── account.service.js
│   │   │       ├── auth.service.js
│   │   │       └── services.module.js
│   │   ├── img
│   │   │   ├── external.png
│   │   │   ├── favicon.png
│   │   │   ├── footer_logo.png
│   │   │   └── logo.png
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── sass
│   │       ├── base
│   │       │   ├── _buttons.scss
│   │       │   ├── _forms.scss
│   │       │   ├── _headings.scss
│   │       │   ├── _list-group.scss
│   │       │   ├── _main.scss
│   │       │   ├── _media.scss
│   │       │   ├── _mixins.scss
│   │       │   ├── _page-header.scss
│   │       │   ├── _scaffolding.scss
│   │       │   ├── _sections.scss
│   │       │   ├── _table.scss
│   │       │   └── _tabset.scss
│   │       ├── components
│   │       │   ├── _auth.scss
│   │       │   ├── _footer.scss
│   │       │   ├── _header.scss
│   │       │   ├── _panels.scss
│   │       │   ├── _root.scss
│   │       │   ├── _sidebar.scss
│   │       │   └── _tablet.scss
│   │       ├── layout
│   │       │   ├── _loading.scss
│   │       │   └── _smb.scss
│   │       ├── style.scss
│   │       ├── utils
│   │       │   ├── _colors.scss
│   │       │   └── _typography.scss
│   │       └── vendors
│   │           ├── _bootstrap.scss
│   │           ├── _colorpicker.scss
│   │           ├── _fontawesome.scss
│   │           └── _rzslider.scss
│   └── templates.js
├── docker-compose.yml
└── express
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── README.md
    ├── bin
    │   └── index.js
    ├── npm-debug.log
    ├── npm-shrinkwrap.json
    ├── package.json
    └── server
        ├── app.js
        ├── config
        │   └── config.json
        ├── controllers
        │   ├── accounts.js
        │   ├── auth.js
        │   ├── index.js
        │   ├── todoitems.js
        │   └── todos.js
        ├── migrations
        │   ├── 20160717103305-create-todo.js
        │   └── 20160717104733-create-todo-item.js
        ├── models
        │   ├── index.js
        │   ├── todo.js
        │   └── todoitem.js
        ├── routes
        │   └── index.js
        └── services
            ├── account.js
            ├── cpe.js
            ├── device.js
            └── index.js

59 directories, 166 files
```

---

## Back-end

Dockerfile

```
# Create image based on the official Node 6 image from the dockerhub
FROM node:6

RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false nodejs

# Create a directory where our app will be placed
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package.json /usr/src/app

# Install dependecies
RUN npm install

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 3000

# Serve the app
CMD ["node", "server/app.js"]
```

*Do I have any bug in this file above according to my file structure ?*

---

## Front-end

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.6

RUN apk add --update nginx && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/nginx/client-body

COPY files/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY files/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

---

## dockercompose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

    # Define the services/containers to be run
    services:
      angular:
        build: angular # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
        network_mode: bridge
        ports:
        - 8080:80/tcp
        volumes:
        - /Users/bheng/Sites/BASE/angular/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw
    
      express: #name of the second service
        build: express # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "3000:3000" #specify ports forewarding
        mem_limit: 300m
        memswap_limit: 1g
        volumes:
          - .:/home/nodejs/app
          - /home/nodejs/app/node_modules
    
        links:
          - database
    
      database: # name of the third service
        image: postgres
        environment:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ih4cku
        ports:
          - "5432:5432" # specify port forewarding
```

---

## Result

I couldn't get my third instances to start.

I kept getting

```
docker-compose up
Starting base_angular_1 ... 
Starting base_database_1 ... 
Starting base_database_1
Starting base_database_1 ... done
Starting base_express_1 ... 
Starting base_express_1 ... done
Attaching to base_angular_1, base_database_1, base_express_1
database_1  | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-08-30 00:54:24 UTC
database_1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
database_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
database_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

> base_express_1 exited with code 0

How would one go about and debug this further?

Comment: Can you post the contents of server/app.js to assist you better?

Compose is saying it exited successfully, so it is just running once and exiting. It is not starting an actual server or keeping the process alive, which is needed for the container to stay up and running

Answer (score 1):

ok, after you posted your `app.js`, I think I can help you.

When you run node app.js, that app.js is being executed and exiting successfully because it is just a module but no server is starting.

You need a file like this:

create a `bin` folder and inside create a file, name this file `www`
Names are just suggestions, you can name it whatever.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Load any undefined ENV variables
 */
require('dotenv').config();

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('app:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

---

Then make sure you install these packages:

```
npm install debug --save
npm install dotenv --save
```

These can be removed from the `www` file, if you want. I just included them here so my shared `www` file runs.

Then, in your `Dockerfile` for the express app, use:

`node ./bin/www`

This command starts a server, keeps the process alive and serves your app.js express module. Make sure that where you require the `app.js` file in the `www`, matches the location of your file. I put there `../app` in the require.

How to include it in DockerFile?

I recommend this:
create a `start` entry in your `package.json`:

`"start": "node ./bin/www"`

in the `scripts` section.

Then, update your `Dockerfile`:

`CMD npm start` or `CMD ["npm", "start"]`

Comment: @ihue I edited the response to match the port you are using, 3000.